# Send Right Arrow key press using selenium - Chrome(MacOS)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

I am using RobotFramework in Python to automate an application on macOS Chrome browser. I need to send multiple keypresses to scroll my grid to right but with no luck.

I tried using `.sendKeys()`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform()
```

I have read that `sendKeys()` doesn't work with macOS. What can be the alternative?

Comment: ActionChains(self._current_browser()).key_down(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).key_down(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).key_up(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)  try something  like this.

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Do you get errors? If so, what errors? If no errors, what happens? Do the wrong keys get sent? Do they get sent to the wrong place?

Comment: `ActionChains` sends the key to the current focused element when it's not given (your case), while SeleniumLibrary's `Press Key` and selenum's  `element.send_keys()` - to a specific target. Are you sure the focus is correct when your code is ran? And address Bryan Oakley's request for more information, the question in its current form is of low quality.

Comment: @BryanOakley I get an error which says no browser is open and it breaks my tests.

Comment: If you're getting "no browser open", then the problem isn't with `send_keys`, the problem is with the fact that you don't have an open browser.